# C# Trouble Setting Variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to save the object clicked on by the mouse to a seperate variable, but the RaycastHit isn't converting to GameObject, even in an if statement checking its type.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Select : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject selectorPrefab;

    private GameObject selectedObject;
    private GameObject clone;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))//left click
        {
            if(clone)
            {
                Destroy(clone);
            }

            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Ship")
            {
                Vector3 position = hit.transform.position;
                float scaleMultiplier = (hit.transform.localScale.x + hit.transform.localScale.z) / 2;

                clone = Instantiate(selectorPrefab);
                clone.transform.position = position;
                clone.transform.localScale *= scaleMultiplier;

                if(hit is GameObject)//Green underline here
                {
                    selectedObject = hit;//Red underline under "hit"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the relevant technology/API/framework tags.

Comment: selectedObject = hit.transform.gameObject

Comment: Your error message at the red underline is probably about not being able to assign from one type to another. You need to cast it, like `selectedObject = (GameObject)hit;`

Comment: really - if an object passes this `is` test I cant assign it to a variable of that type without a cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the `is` operator doesn't change the compile-time type of the `hit` variable. You could either cast within your `if` body, or use `as` instead:

```
var hitGameObject = hit as GameObject
if (hitGameObject != null)
{
    selectedObject = hitGameObject;
}
```

In C# 7 you could introduce a new variable in the `if` statement instead:

```
if (hit is GameObject hitGameObject)
{
    selectedObject = hitGameObject;
}
```

But if you know that it will *always* be a `GameObject` (barring bugs), just cast:

```
// No if statement, just an unconditional cast
selectedObject = (GameObject) hit;
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of a raycast, RaycastHit, is not a GameObject; instead it contains a set of information about the detected hit which you can see listed here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html

The object you're looking for is `hit.collider`, which is a component of the hit GameObject that represents its volume in Physics-space; you can retrieve the overall GameObject with `hit.collider.gameObject`.